# Java movement in opposite direction cancels itself for a brief moment

Tags: java

I am trying to make a smooth movement in Java
and after watching some videos on YouTube,
I recreated it,
but found a bug that was missed in the video.
If you quickly press a key for moving in opposing directions after letting go of the first key
(example: you move right,
let go of right,
then press "left"
there is a small stagger).
Does anyone have any ideas for this?

This is mine Main class where the listeners are:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            p.setVelX(5);
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            p.setVelX(-5);
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP || key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            p.setVelY(-5);      
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        {
            p.setVelY(5);
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !isShooting)
        {
            isShooting = true;
            c.addBullet(new Bullet(p.getX(), p.getY(), tex));
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            p.setVelX(0);
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            p.setVelX(0);
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP || key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            p.setVelY(0);       
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        {
            p.setVelY(0);
        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            isShooting = false;
            c.addBullet(new Bullet(p.getX(), p.getY(), tex));
        }
    }
```

And this is mine Player class:

```
public void tick()
    {
        x+=velX;
        y+=velY;

    }

    public double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(double x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(double y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setVelX(double velX)
    {
        this.velX = velX;
    }

    public void setVelY(double velY)
    {
        this.velY = velY;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing some answers, I found a solution:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        isRight = true; //if the key is pressed
        p.setVelX(5);
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        isLeft = true; //if the key is pressed
        p.setVelX(-5);
    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        isRight = false;
        if(!isLeft) p.setVelX(0); //if you are not going the other direction stop
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the keys `ifPressed` flags somewhere and handle the keyRelease for a direction if only opposite direction is released as well like:

```
if((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || key == KeyEvent.VK_D) && !isLeftPressed)
{
    p.setVelX(0);
    isRightPressed = false;
}
```

Comment: When I tried your solution, I stumbled on a kinda rare bug: If I switch too fast multiple times, the game will start thinking that the last key is always TRUE, and the character keeps going in the certain direction forever, without stopping.